# How do I search a column for multiple values, and if found, populate another column on the same row?

Tags: r, dataframe, search, grepl

Within my data, I have x20 specific datasets that have missing values in an 'Order' column.

I need to search down a 'Participant_ID' column for these particular datasets - (I have a list of the IDs of interest) - and when located, add the letter "A" to the 'Order' column of each corresponding row.

I've found out how to do this for one participant at a time, but I can't figure out how to get this code to repeat for a list of participant IDs:

```r
df$Order <- ifelse(grepl("participant1_ID_number", df$Participant_ID), "A", "")
```

This works well, but if I copy and paste the same line beneath it, replacing "participant1_ID_number" for "participant2_ID_number", the first change is undone.

Comment: `df$Order <- ifelse(grepl("participant1_ID_number", df$Participant_ID), "A", df$Order )` results in your result not getting overwritten.

Comment: This worked, thanks!